# How can I map a list of values to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to map some values to a dataframe, i used some looping methods but it seems that there must be a simple way to acheive the result im looking for

input_df :

```
A B C
x y z
i j t
f g h
```

list if values to map :

```
list = [1,2,3]
```

result_df :

```
A B C D
x y z 1
i j t 1
f g h 1
x y z 2
i j t 2
f g h 2
x y z 3
i j t 3
f g h 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `cross` join (i.e. Cartesian product):

```py
tmp = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=["D"])
tmp.merge(input_df, how="cross")
```

Require pandas >= 1.2.0. [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)